# In gradle, a maven artifact without a pom file works from jcenter but not mavenCentral

Tags: maven, gradle, jcenter

I have a Java project using gradle that uses some very old dependencies.  One of them has a transitive dependency that works fine with `jcenter()` but now fails when I try to migrate to `mavenCentral()`.  The artifact exists in Maven Central but has no pom file.  Gradle gives me an error like this:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':myproject:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find woodstox:wstx-asl:3.2.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.7/wstx-asl-3.2.7.pom
```

Any attempt on my part to browse the jcenter repository returns a 403 Forbidden so I can't tell if the pom file exists there but somehow Gradle is able to build the project using `jcenter()`.

That leaves me with a few questions:

1. Are pom files required in (very old) maven artifacts?
2. How does gradle gain access to https://jcenter.bintray.com/?
3. Is there any way to find out if the jcenter artifact has a pom file?
4. If it doesn't have a pom file, why does gradle work with `jcenter()` but fails with `mavenCentral`?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It does simply does not work https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.7/ because they are missing which means broken deps because of missing pom files which means they are not consumable by others. Furthermore bintray is simply down. That means if you don't find those artifacts on other existing repository you seemed to be out of luck...

Comment: I was able to find the pom file in my gradle cache so I copied it to our S3 maven repo and that allowed it to compile again.  It seems like an issue that gradle never complained when jcenter (which was offline) was used with --refresh-dependencies.